# HTML Javascript - Replace a button with a search field onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple button:

```
<p><button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-parks"
onclick="search()">Get started today</a></p>
```

On click I want to completely replace the above code with a search field. I'm wondering what the best way is to replace the code above with the code for the search field onclick using JavaScript or JQuery.

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="container-1">
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
      <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `onclick="search(this)"` and `element.outerHTML='NEW HTML'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `element.outerHTML='NEW HTML'`

To get the current element, pass `this` as argument

To replace `p` element as well, Use `elem.parentElement.outerHTML` => `parentElement` will return parent node of the owner node..

Try this:

```js
var html = '<div class="box">\
  <div class="container-1">\
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>\
      <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />\
  </div>\
</div>';

function search(elem) {
  elem.outerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-parks" onclick="search(this)">Get started today</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all - your code is not valid: tag starts as `<button>` but ends as `</a>`.

To hide initial search `.box` you can place it in `<script>` tag and set it's `type` attribute to unrecognizable (random text). After clicking button take this template inner html and replace it with your code.

Also I have passed `this` to function to get element you clicked, so you can have multiple same purpose elements.

```js
function search(el) {
  $(el)
    .parents()
    .eq(1)
    .html($('#box-tpl').html())
  ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-parks" onclick="search(this)">Get started today</button>
  </p>
</div>

On click I want to completely replace the above code with a search field. I'm wondering what the best way is to replace the code above with the code for the search field onclick using JavaScript or JQuery.

<script type="text/tmpl" id="box-tpl">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="container-1">
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
      <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use onclick

```
$('#id').on('click', function(e){

        $('#id').replaceWith('<input type="text"  name="q" size="25"  id="newelement" value=""/>');


    });
```

if you want cursor in input field in onclick event

```
        $("newelement").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function search(){
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-lg btn-success btn-parks');
    var button0 = button[0];

    button0.outerHTML = ('<div class="box"> <div class="container-1"> <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span> <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..."/> </div></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's hide() and show() functions:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.button').hide();
    $('.box').show();
});
```

```js
$('button').click(function(){
 $('.button').hide();
 $('.box').show();
});
```

```css
.box{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="button">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-parks" onclick="search()">Get started today</button>
</p>
<div class="box">
    <div class="container-1">
        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
        <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle with Bootstrap styles](https://jsfiddle.net/nk3su6n6/)